# Can't find variable: Dimensions

Tags: react-native

When I try to use:

```
const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');
```

On a react native component, I get a weird error never seen before:

Can't find variable: Dimensions

[image: screenshot of the error]

Have someone face this issue before?

```
"dependencies": {
"expo": "^22.0.0",
"react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-22.0.2.tar.gz"
```

},

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Fix it... my mistake, I should import from react-native Dimensions.

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';
```